# Strange MS Access error related to SQL Server User Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vba, ms-access

Im having a strange issues in an MS Access database that links to SQL Server 2008. In the database, I have a function that is called on start up to add a record to a table. When doing so, I get an error of "OBDC Connection Failed". After doing some testing, I was able to find that if the user within the database is a "db_owner" they are allowed to add the record without any issues. However, if they are a "db_datawriter/db_datareader" they cannot.

Anyone have this issue before?

Comment: What do you see when you run a trace while user is dbwriter/dbreader?

Comment: Excuse my ingnorance, but how would I do so?

Comment: Set up a trace in Profiler and filter on the username, then try to run the update.  Be sure to include errors.